# How to get the negation of \rightsquigarrow? something like \neq or \nleftrightarrow

Tags: amsmath

I am able to produce `\rightsquigarrow`. Now I want to get the negation of this arrow, something like `\neq`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\not`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\(A \rightsquigarrow B\)

\(A \not\rightsquigarrow B\)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MnSymbol` package has a `\nrightlsquigarrow` macro:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\begin{document}

$\rightlsquigarrow$

$\nrightlsquigarrow$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It also gave me another alternative to get the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

A little variance of the @Vincent's answer using `slashed` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{slashed}

\begin{document}
$A \rightsquigarrow B$

$A \mathrel{\slashed{\rightsquigarrow}} B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved my problem.